# NUnit Categories in combination?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tdd, nunit

In my NUnit testfixtrues i have something along the lines of

```
[Test,Category("catA")]
public void test1
{
    //
}

[Test,Category("catB")]
public void test2
{
    //
}

[Test,Category("catA")]
[Test,Category("catB")]
public void test3
{
    //
}
```

Now in the NUnit gui i want to be able to select catA and catB and run the tests where catA **and** catB are present.  Currently this is not the case and NUnit will run all 3 tests.

Is there any way to change this behavior to an AND condition rather than OR?

I'm currently running v2.5.0.9122.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure about the GUI, but you can do this from the console.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19036057/206297.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The quick answer from 2019 for NUnit 3.0.
It's possible to use multiple categories.

Consider the following example:

```cs
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests1
    {
        [Test]
        [Category("A")]
        public void TestA()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("B")]
        public void TestB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("C")]
        public void TestC()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("A")]
        [Category("B")]
        public void TestAB()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("A")]
        [Category("C")]
        public void TestAC()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("B")]
        [Category("C")]
        public void TestBC()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
        }

        [Test]
        [Category("A")]
        [Category("B")]
        [Category("C")]
        public void TestABC()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
        }
    }
```

You can run the tests with both categories `A` and `B` and excluding category `C` using this command argument: `--where="cat==A && cat==B && cat!=C"`

[image]

Or you can run the tests with any of categories `A` and `B` and excluding `C` like this: `--where="(cat==A || cat==B) && cat!=C"`

[image]

Answer (score 20):

based on the docs, you just say /include:CatA+CatB

http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.5.1

Specifying Test Categories to Include or Exclude

NUnit provides CategoryAttribute for use in marking tests as belonging
 to one or more categories. Categories may be included or excluded in a
 test run using the /include and /exclude options. The following
 command runs only the tests in the BaseLine category:

nunit-console myassembly.dll /include:BaseLine The following command runs all tests except those in the Database category:

nunit-console myassembly.dll /exclude:Database Multiple categories may be specified on either option, by using commas to  separate them.

Notes: Beginning with NUnit 2.4, the /include and /exclude options may
be combined on the command line. When both are used, all tests with
the included categories are run except for those with the excluded
categories.

Beginning with NUnit 2.4.6, you may use a Category Expression with
either of these options:

- A|B|C Selects tests having any of the categories A, B or C.
- A,B,C Selects tests having any of the categories A, B or C.
- A+B+C Selects only tests having all three of the categories assigned
- A+B|C Selects tests with both A and B OR with category C.
- A+B-C Selects tests with both A and B but not C.
- -A Selects tests not having category A assigned
- A+(B|C) Selects tests having both category A and either of B or C
  The comma operator is equivalent to | but has a higher precendence. Order of evaluation is
  as follows:

  Unary exclusion operator (-) High-precendence union operator (,)
  Intersection and set subtraction operators (+ and binary -)
  Low-precedence union operator (|) Note: Because the operator
  characters have special meaning, you should avoid creating a category
  that uses any of them in it's name. For example, the category
  "db-tests" could not be used on the command line, since it appears to
  means "run category db, except for category tests." The same
  limitation applies to characters that have special meaning for the
  shell you are using.

Comment: This seems to be underreferenced somehow. Never saw that category logic from 2.4.6 before. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: J4SONc - That must have been added after my time on the project. That's cool. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 16):

No. There is no way to only run tests that belong to two, or more, specific categories. To be honest when we first put the feature in several years ago I never thought of that. We tried to keep it as simple as possible.

By the way, you don't need to specify `[Test]` twice on your `test3` method.

```
[Test]
[Category("catA")]
[Category("catB")]
public void test3
{
    //
}
```

Not that it makes a difference. It's just a style preference.

Comment: Viewers of this page should note that this answer is now out of date. It is now possible - [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19036057/1158174). I only mention it as I nearly missed it.

Answer (score 5):

If you use version 3.0 use the  option `--where`.
Example:

```
nunit3-console.exe youdll.dll --where="cat==yourCat"
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you need is a third category of "catAandB".

Comment: Yes. To give a more concrete example, I have a category called "Integration". I have a second category called "Database" which is a strict subset of "Integration". So "Integration" is like "catAandB".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't chose both of them as NUnit stands.

I tried a number of different things with NUnit and the way that my tests were created with no success.

I have found a [site](http://www.bryancook.net/2008/06/tdd-custom-nunit-categories.html) that talks you through the process of creating custom category attributes but still can't see how that may help.

Comment: yeah, i came across that one too.  I'll take another look and have a think how i could go about bending it to my will but i think a change to the nunit gui may be in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
"...nunit-console.exe" "....myassembly.dll" /include:catA+catB
```