# nunit3 how to include test category in command line

Tags: nunit

```
nunit3-console TestData.dll /include:SmokeTests
```

but with nunit v3 I get back:

```
Invalid argument: /include:SmokeTests
```

I try to check command line parameters here
http://nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=3.0

but page does not exist. Anyone know what has changed?

Comment: Try the following link https://github.com/nunit/nunit/wiki/Console-Command-Line

Answer (score 27, accepted):

So if anyone searching how to do this in NUNIT3:

```
 --where "cat == SmokeTests" --noresult
```

helped by @omer727 link!

Comment: This link provides details on the where syntax: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language

Answer (score 7):

Link provided by @omer727 is broken, here is another one: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

The anwser still works:

```
--where "cat == SmokeTests"
```

The console command-line allows you to specify a filter, which will select which tests are executed. This is done using the --where option, followed by an expression in NUnit's Test Selection Language (TSL), a simple domain-specific language designed for this purpose.

Example:

```
nunit3-console mytest.dll --where "cat == Urgent || Priority == High"
```

For more details visit this link: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language

**EDIT:**

The detailed example can be found in the related SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876429/4185987).

Comment: can you help me in doing this with AutoRun().Execute() . I run test with category attribute as ``.Execute(new String[] { "--where= cat=testname"});`` now how to add `--params` in this?

Comment: and if you have a space in the category ` --where "cat == 'Integration Tests'" `

Answer (score 1):

I'm using nUnit 3.4, and

```
--where "cat != blah"
```

did not work. I had to add colon

```
--where:"cat != blah"
```

Was running the command from powershell.