# Managing selenium specflow tests across environments

Tags: selenium-webdriver, specflow

For a project, I have these environments:
Dev 
Qa 
Int 
Stage 
Prod

The environments after QA  are environments that have integrated data coming from external system. Is there any way I can setup my test project to toggle selenium steps to run based on environments?

Answer (score 0):

In SpecFlow you can categorize you scenarios/features using [Tags](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags). In runners you can filter test by this category (e.g. [nunit3 how to include test category in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103853/nunit3-how-to-include-test-category-in-command-line)). In Visual Studio Test Explorer you group them [by traits](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270865.aspx#BKMK_Group_by_traits).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the SpecFlow+Runner and his Targets- Feature.
An example how to use it with different browsers can be found here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest
Documentation: http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/Targets/

Exchange the different browsers to your environments.

You get for every target a customized app.config, which you can read out in your steps.

---

Full disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow+